# How to Style a cell in Gridview under ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

How to style every cell in Gridview.I want my cell text in a rounded text box with red background.My code is

```
<ListView Margin="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding ParamList}" >
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView  >
            <GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" Height="75" MinWidth="60"  >
                        <Border.Background>Gray</Border.Background>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="WhiteSmoke" Margin="5" 
                                   Text="{Binding}" Width="Auto" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>

            <GridViewColumn Header="category1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=param1}"   />
            <GridViewColumn Header="category2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=param1}" />

        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the GridViewColumn's CellTemplate property to set a DataTemplate containing a TextBox with the appropriate styling for each of your columns.  I don't believe there is a way to set it at the Gridview level so that you don't have to set it on each column individually.

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="{Binding Item1}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have  very large number of columns and every cell template is going to be the same apart from binding (in this example I have added only two columns).I am looking for something I can do at Grid View level,but thanks for your answer.

Comment: You could specify the DatatTemplate as a resource on the ListView, and just reference each for each column to cut down on the XAML.  Alternatively, you might want to use a DataGrid instead of a ListView - it is generally a lot more customizable, and has a CellTemplate property that will apply to all cells

Comment: Can you please give example for DatatTemplate as a resource on the ListView,How would it take care of binding?